# Making a vuetify autocomplete with composition api and remote api?

Tags: vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

The problem is the following :

How do you manage to make an API call, using Vuetify autocomplete and the brand new composition api ?

Comment: Can you provide more details? There are multiple implementations possible using the Vuetify autocomplete component. Like, do you want to make an API call and use the returned data to populate the autocomplete dropdown?

Comment: Exactly that, api call and populate the autocomplete dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem that different from Vue 2.

in main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

import App from './App.vue'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify({}),
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

in `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app" data-app>
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="model"
      :items="items"
      item-text="first_name"
      item-value="id"
      label="Select a user..."
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted }  from '@vue/composition-api'

export default {
  setup() {
    const model = ref(null)
    const items = ref()

    const getUsers = async () => {
      const { data } = await (
        await  fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
      ).json()

      items.value = data
    }

    onMounted(getUsers)

    return {
      model,
      items,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I did it in a codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-autocomplete-basic-p6q9m?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Hi Casey thanks for posting that answer. Would you know how to access this code with context in the composition api?  this.$vuetify.goTo(9999, {
              duration: 600,
              offset: 0,
              easing: "easeInOutQuint"
            });

Comment: Hi @TravisKlein, yeah, if you want to run that method in the template just remove this. If you're trying to access $vuetify in your setup function. You can access it through the context object, like so: const myComponent = { setup(_, context) { context.root.$vuetify }  }

Comment: Aww yes the context.root.$vuetify.goTo() was the answer. I figured that out a hour after I posted but I couldn't find how to find my comment posts on stack to get back to edit my comment. Anyways thanks for the reply!